# How can I reverse engineer a self-contained dotnet executable on MacOS?

Tags: .net, macos

For a challenge at OWASP WrongSecrets I have build a self-contained binary to be reverse engineered (see https://github.com/OWASP/wrongsecrets-binaries/actions/runs/8244751569), but, I have not been able to find the secret with Ghidra or Radare2 on MacOS. How can I best find the secret using tools on Linux or MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

Self-contained executable are usually an executable part and attached inside the executable the DotNet assembly dll files. Decompiling using Ghidra/Radare first will get you into the executable part which is not application-specific, but the DotNet runtime.

Therefore I recommend using a DotNet decompiler like [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases). It is capable of loading the assembly DLL files included in the executable and decompile e.g. the Main method of the DotNet application (see assembly `dotnetproject`).

Unfortunately ILSpy is a Windows program and not available for MacOS. Homebrew has an [ilspy cask](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/ilspy), but that only installs an old  Avalonia, an old and discontinued port of ILSpy. I am not sure if that port is already able to open and decompile the packed DotNet executable.

Comment: Thank you sir! The lispy cask gave metadata errors when I tried to open the file… is there an alternative possible for Linux/Macos besides running a VM?